# Thread synchronization (locking) that only releases to the last-in thread

Tags: c#, locking, mutex, cancellationtokensource

What is the proper way to ensure that only the 'last-in' thread is given access to a mutex/locked region while intermediary threads do not acquire the lock?

Example sequence:

```
A acquires lock
B waits
C waits
B fails to acquire lock*
A releases lock
C acquires lock
```

*B should fail to acquire the lock either via an exception (as in `SemaphoreSlim.Wait(CancellationToken)` or a boolean `Monitor.TryEnter()` type construct.

I can think of several similar schemes to achieve this (such as using a `CancellationTokenSource` and `SemaphoreSlim`), but none of them seem particularly elegant.

Is there a common practice for this scenario?

Comment: This is an interesting question - so what would happen if - between `A` releasing the lock and `C` getting it - `D` comes in? I'm just curious - trying to think up a scenario where this approach would be required.

Comment: I'm sorry, didnt understand "B fails" what to you mean by that ? U frozen the thread from thread window ?

Comment: @xxbbcc The desired result is that the last-in (D in your scenario) successfully acquires the lock while intermediate threads do not (B & C do not enter the locked section).

Comment: @Kapoor I mean that B fails to acquire the lock, either via an exception (as in `SemaphoreSlim.Wait(CancellationToken`) or a boolean `Monitor.TryEnter` type construct.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon Yes, that's what I suspected. It's very hard to define what "last-in" is, though. I guess once the process of granting the lock to a thread begins, any new threads are "first-in".

Comment: @xxbbcc Basically as soon as a new thread enters the wait queue, all other waiting threads are 'cancelled'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work like you want, it uses a SemaphoreSlim with a size of 1 to control it. I also added support for passing in a CancelationToken to cancel waiting for the lock early, it also supports `WaitAsync` returning a task instead of blocking.

```
public sealed class LastInLocker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public void Wait()
    {
        Wait(CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public void Wait(CancellationToken earlyCancellationToken)
    {
        if(_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("LastInLocker");

        var token = ReplaceTokenSource(earlyCancellationToken);
        _semaphore.Wait(token);
    }

    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
        return WaitAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public async Task WaitAsync(CancellationToken earlyCancellationToken)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("LastInLocker");

        var token = ReplaceTokenSource(earlyCancellationToken);

        //I await here because if ReplaceTokenSource thows a exception I want the 
        //observing of that exception to be deferred until the caller awaits my 
        //returned task.
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("LastInLocker");

        _semaphore.Release();
    }

    private CancellationToken ReplaceTokenSource(CancellationToken earlyCancellationToken)
    {
        var newSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(earlyCancellationToken);
        var oldSource = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _cts, newSource);
        oldSource.Cancel();
        oldSource.Dispose();

        return newSource.Token;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposed = true;

        _semaphore.Dispose();
        _cts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is a little test program that re-creates your test example

```
internal class Program
{
    static LastInLocker locker = new LastInLocker();
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => Test("A"));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Task.Run(() => Test("B"));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Task.Run(() => Test("C"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Test(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} waits for lock", name);
        try
        {
            locker.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} acquires lock", name);

            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            locker.Release();

            Console.WriteLine("{0} releases lock", name);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} fails to acquire lock", name);
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
A waits for lock
A acquires lock
B waits for lock
C waits for lock
B fails to acquire lock
A releases lock
C acquires lock
C releases lock
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for the detailed answer. This is very close to the method that I have been using (just replacing the internal lock with an Interlocked.Exchange). But wrapping it in a reusable class is a very nice touch.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon I wanted the `.Cancel()` and the new token assignment to be a atomic operation, otherwise I would have likely done similar. I with a little re-writing I think I could do it with a InterlockedExchange but this lock is likely going to be very small and most often uncontended so the overhead is not that bad.

Comment: I had been hoping / thinking that there should be a simpler primitive to accomplish this scenario, but it may in fact be the right approach.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon it was easy enough once I tried to think about it, I updated the answer with `Interlocked.Exchange`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public interface ILocker
{
    bool GetLock();

    void Release();
}

class Locker : ILocker
{
    private long m_NumberOfTimeGetLockWasCalled = 0;

    private readonly object m_LockingObject = new object();

    private readonly object m_LockingObject2 = new object();

    public bool GetLock()
    {

        long lock_count = 0;

        var lock_was_taken = false;

        lock(m_LockingObject)
        {
            lock_count = m_NumberOfTimeGetLockWasCalled++;

            lock_was_taken = Monitor.TryEnter(m_LockingObject2);

            if (lock_was_taken)
                return true;

        }

        while(!lock_was_taken)
        {

            Thread.Sleep(5);

            lock(m_LockingObject)
            {

                if (lock_count != m_NumberOfTimeGetLockWasCalled)
                    return false;

                lock_was_taken = Monitor.TryEnter(m_LockingObject2);

                if (lock_was_taken)
                    break;

            }


        }


        return true;
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(m_LockingObject2);
    }
}
```